# Is there a way to make a resizable fullscreen window in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I need a window in Pygame that is created in fullscreen, but the user can hover to the top and exit fullscreen if they want to. I have tried `pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), flags=pygame.FULLSCREEN | pygame.RESIZABLE | pygame.SCALED, vsync=1)` but I am not able to hover to the top and press the buttons to exit fullscreen. If I take out the `pygame.FULLSCREEN` flag, it is opened in windowed mode but I am able to toggle fullscreen by pressing the button in the corner of the window. When I enter full screen this way, I can still use the buttons to exit the screen, but not when the `pygame.FULLSCREEN` flag is used. `pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()` also does not produce the desired result.

I am on a Mac if that makes any difference.